# Shorter way to convert object entries to array while flattening the contained arrays of objects? (improve my solution)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this:

```
export default {
  characters: {
    hero: { h: 1 },

    boundaries: { b: 1 },

    zombies: [{ z: 1 }, { z: 2 }, { z: 3 }],
    bullets: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],
  },
};
```

I need to create an array from it that looks something like this, but the order would not be important:

```
[ { h: 1 }, { b: 1 }, { z: 1 }, { z: 2 }, { z: 3 }, { b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 } ]
```

and my current solution works but it seems like it **could be improved** to be more eloquent and use less lines of code.

```
import gameState from './modules/gameState.js';
let toRender = [];

Object.keys(gameState.characters).forEach(e => {
  if (Array.isArray(gameState.characters[e])) {
    toRender.push(...gameState.characters[e]);
  } else {
    toRender.push(gameState.characters[e]);
  }
});

renderScreen(toRender);

function renderScreen(theArgs) {
  theArgs.forEach(character => {
    character.draw();
  });
}
```

Comment: I would just use an array for hero and boundaries as well, so it becomes a simple: `Object.values(characters).reduce((a,b) =>a.concat(b));`  since you usually have multiple boundaries and can them support multiple characters in the future, even if you don't at the moment.

Comment: @Shilly thanks, but I want to access the properties of gameState.characters.hero.xPos and things like that and having it in an array would confuse things.

Comment: If you are interested in these kind of things, I would advice to read https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/07_elife.html . Things like putting the position of things inside a view instead of onto the character object reduced the amount of complex reductions I needed by alot.

Comment: @Shilly thanks! I am very interested in these things, I will check out your link. If you are also interested in framework free game programming in general then check out this http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `reduce` with `concat` on `Object.values`.

```js
const data = {characters: {hero: { h: 1 },boundaries: { b: 1 },zombies: [{ z: 1 }, { z: 2 }, { z: 3 }],bullets: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],},};
const result = Object.values(data.characters).reduce((r, e) => r.concat(e), []);
console.log(result)
```

You can also just use spread syntax `...` with `concat` on `Object.values`.

```js
const data = {characters: {hero: { h: 1 },boundaries: { b: 1 },zombies: [{ z: 1 }, { z: 2 }, { z: 3 }],bullets: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],},};
const result = [].concat(...Object.values(data.characters))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const characters= {
    hero: { h: 1 },
    boundaries: { b: 1 },
    zombies: [{ z: 1 }, { z: 2 }, { z: 3 }],
    bullets: [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],
  };

console.log([].concat.apply([],Object.values(characters).map(v=>v)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Comment: You could also just use `[].concat(...Object.values(characters))`

Comment: @NenadVracar that might be the best! you should submit it as an answer :)